# After writing Jetson Nano .img file, my sd card is suddenly divided in multiple partitions

Tags: image, sd-card, nvidia-jetson

1. Formatting my sd card in ExFAT type.
2. Writing Jetson nano image file(official one) to sd card using 'Etcher' app.
3. after the work, sd card does not mount well on MacOS and it is divided in 12 partitions with GUID partition map.
   When I mount the sdcard on Windows, so many pop-ups (maybe the number of them is 12) come out and I can't do anything with this sd card.

I did same things with many sd cards(128GB, 32GB etc).
regardless of whether cards have mounted at Jetson nano board.

so I think there are some collisions between the formatting process and writing img process...

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your Jetson. The SD card is, indeed, partitioned into many partitions but this is not a problem as the card normally should stay within Jetson, you do not need to remove it and connect to another computer.

When you flash Jetson with NVIDIA package manager, it may happen that Linux partition goes first, then other partitions follow, and large unusable space remains at the end. In such case, write down the name, UUID of the ext4 partition and then use Linux tools (dd, tune2fs) from another machine to fix the layout so that all names and UUIDs stay as they initially were. But this mess normally does not happen when you download and flash the card image yourself. Just do not care about these partitions. Enjoy Jetson.